# Can't load native library(OpenCV) in java

Tags: java, opencv

I have problem with my app in java + opencv (eclipse).

It's working in eclipse just fine. when i make jar from my project its working on my laptop but on diffrent PC where i run the jar(PC without IDE) i cant load opencv.
Present method of loading openCV:

```
static {
    try {
        int bitness = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
        if(bitness == 32){
            System.out.println("32 bit detected");
            System.load("C:/OpenCV/opencv/build/java/x86/opencv_java248.dll");
        }
        else if (bitness == 64){
            System.out.println("64 bit detected");
            System.load("C:/OpenCV/opencv/build/java/x64/opencv_java248.dll");
        }
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
```

I get error message about UnsatisfiedLinkError. when i try to print e.getMessege() in my catch section i get empty message.

When I was using 
System.loadLibrary("opencv_java248") or
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME) with and without -Djava.library.path=(pathToLibrary) with good version of opencv_java248, by good i mean i dont have any typo in path or library version, i had error message:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError:
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
...
```

--EDIT

dependency walker show only msjava.dll missing. but it shouldn't be a problem.. 
I changed opencv folder and now i have C:/opencv/build/java/..

and stil nothing

Comment: Just a couple thoughts:  You might want to install at /opencv instead of /OpenCv/opencv.  I think it makes assumptions about where it's installed, and not sure how to override those assumptions.  Do you have these or appropriate alternates in your System PATH?  C:\opencv\build\java\x86;C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin.  I'll be deploying my app to different places soon, I'd be interested in knowing if you find a solution.

Comment: One other thought -- I've received the UnsatisfiedLinkError when the the DLL wasn't able to find some of its dependencies.  Running something like Dependency Walker on opencv_java248.dll on the different PC might shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Got OpenCv/opencv on my PC where i develop app, so i use it on a diffrent one too. Also got folder with opencv dll on System PATH; Tomorrow i'll write about dependency walker.